# json -schema object Validation in Ruby

Tags: ruby

1.Below is the ruby code with json - schema validations, Here the point is i want to validate only object instead of its properties

```
require "json-schema"
schema={"type"=>"object"}
begin
    JSON::Validator.validate(schema,{"a":5})
rescue JSON::Schema::ValidationError => e
    puts e.message
end
```

2. For example the key values of object can be anything, just i want to validate, whether {"a":"5"} it is an object/Hash or not instead of checking its properties like "a":5.

Answer (score 0):

### You Have Invalid Ruby Syntax

`JSON:Validator` is invalid namespacing. You need two colons when specifying a nested module or class, so use `JSON::Validator` instead. When you fix that, your test schema will validate. For example:

```
require 'json-schema'

schema={'type' => 'object'}
JSON::Validator.validate(schema, {'a': 5})
#=> true
```

You may have other problems, too, but they aren't evident from your example, since almost everything descends from Object. If you run into problems with specific types, you may want to take action on the value of *e* in your rescued SON::Schema::ValidationError, especially if it's essentially a form of TypeError.